# Complete checkout without shipping method available

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

For example, I have only one shipping method (Flat Rate) configured that is available for the US country only. When another country selected and the "No shipping method available" message received I still want to proceed with payment as I will send custom shipping offer to the client via E-Mail. By default, if no shipping method selected I could not finish the checkout.

How is it possible to proceed with payment in checkout without shipping method for address entered available?

A virtual product is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you create a 'hidden' shipping method for those people and then just hide it so they don't see it and enable it for the non US people? Then after order placement you send the shipping offer to the customers that have that second 'hidden' shipping method?